# Error: No provider for Router! when launching my test with karma in Angular4

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I have the following code:

```
class RouterStub {
    navigate(url: String) { return url; 
}

describe('OwnersComponent', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                OwnersComponent
            ],
            providers: [
                { provide: OwnersService, useClass: OwnersService },
                { provide: Router, useClass: RouterStub }
            ]
        });
        TestBed.compileComponents();
    });
```

With the following test:

```
it('navigate when details clicked',
    inject([Router], (router: Router) => {

        const spy = spyOn(router, 'navigateByUrl');

        const navArgs = spy.calls.first().args[0];

        const id = comp.owners[0].id;
        expect(navArgs).toBe('/owners/detail');
    }));
```

As you can see, im adding as a provider my Router and using it via inject, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: No provider for Router!
```

If I'm not wrong, `inject` uses the current TestBed injector and my service is not being provided by the components injector so it should be working.

I've also tried manually importing `RouterTestingModule` into my `TestBed` configuration.

Comment: It should work. Check this example and try to reproduce it https://plnkr.co/edit/Wwbefb4SHEdWyh5kJn62?p=preview

Comment: This is working, now I have to figure what is happening in my code, seems strange because the error points directly to the router, it doesn't looks like it is a nested exception (at least while debugging). The error log isn't that helpful so I'm gonna try with a try catch.